# How do you catch errors on PouchDB creation?

Tags: pouchdb

I can't figure out where I can catch a failed attempt at accessing a remote couchdb in pouch. For example:

`var testPouchDB = new PouchDB('http://remotedb-url/non-existant-db-name);`

If the user's not able to create that database due to permissions, this error is thrown:

`CustomPouchError {status: 401, name: "unauthorized", message: "Name or password is incorrect.", error: true, reason: "You are not a server admin."}`

My build setup may be hiding where this is thrown, as dev tools says it's at `undefined:1`, but also from the [API docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database) I can't figure out how I'm supposed to catch db creation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `db.info()` and then verify that the request works.

Answer (score 0):

I caught a similar error when trying to replicate a local database to a remote one that didn't exist.  My error was caught in the replication event's error handler:

```
const remoteUserDB = new PouchDB('http://remote-url/db-name', {
  auth: ...
});

localDB.replicate.to(remoteUserDB, {
  live: true,
  retry: true
}).on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('error: ', err);  // <-- Caught here
});
```

This might help others with similar problems.